# Laravel - Builder object returned instead of Collection

Tags: php, laravel, collections, builder

I have written a query to filter my products. This is my code:

```
    $products = \DB::table('products')->select('*');
    foreach ($request->all() as $cat => $subCat) {
        if($subCat != '*') {
            $products->where('id', $subCat);
        }
    }
    $products->get();
```

However, the query returns a Builder object and I can't figure out why.

What is exactly wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: What you get in `$request->all()` ? .Also share complete code how you return value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt you haven't assign value into variable, try this

```
$products = $products->get();
```